# VBA/ How to close Project Explorer window with a shortcut

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to close a Project Explorer window with a shortcut or is there an option to write a Subroutine closing this window?

Comment: Do you mean collapse a specific project within project explorer, or actually close the project explorer totally?

Comment: Actually close the window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a routine like this:

```
Sub ClosePE_Window()
   Dim w As Object
   For Each w In Application.VBE.Windows
      If LCase$(Left$(w.Caption, 10)) = "project - " Then
         w.Close
         Exit For
      End If
   Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the windows captions vary due to regional settings; for instance in German it would start with "Projekt -" @Rory